# How Can I Use ONLY Slug For Categories, Posts and Pages at the same time in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to code a CMS with laravel. I want to use slug for categories, pages and for posts at the same time.

Posts: `www.domain.com/slug`

Categories: `www.domain.com/slug`

Pages: `www.domain.com/slug`

`Controller` Page:

```php
public function categories($slug)
{
  $settings = Settings::find(1);
  $categories = Categories::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
  $posts = Posts::where('category', '=', $categories->id)->get();
  return view('web.'.$settings->template.'.category',compact('posts','categories'));
}

public function posts($slug)
{
  $categories = Categories::all();
  $settings = Settings::find(1);
  $posts = Posts::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
  return view('web.'.$settings->template.'.single',compact('posts','similars','categories'));
}
```

`Web.php`

```
Route::get('/{slug}','HomeController@categories')->name('show.category');
Route::get('/{slug}','HomeController@pages')->name('show.page');
Route::get('/{slug}','HomeController@posts')->name('show.post');
```

With that codes I got this error -> `https://prnt.sc/pp9196`

And if I remove the codes for similar posts I got this error. -> `https://prnt.sc/pp91u1`

So how can I use the only slug for those pages?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 3 routes with the same URL like that. You need to differentiate them somehow. The simplest way would be an identifier prior to `{slug}`:

```
Route::get('/categories/{slug}','HomeController@categories')->name('show.category');
Route::get('/pages/{slug}','HomeController@pages')->name('show.page');
Route::get('/posts/{slug}','HomeController@posts')->name('show.post');
```

Comment: there must be a way to do it. There are lots of websites like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new method on your controller:

```
public function show($slug) {
    return $this->posts($slug) || $this->categories($slug) || $this->pages($slug) || abort(404)
}
```

You can change the order of calls here to give different priority (only makes sense if your slug is not unique)

Then modify your `posts()`, `pages()` and `categories()` methods to return null if not found:

```
public function categories($slug)
{
  $categories = Categories::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
  // Moved top because makes no sense load settings if the category doesn't exists.

  if (!$categories) {
    return null
  }

  $settings = Settings::find(1);
  $posts = Posts::where('category', '=', $categories->id)->get();
  return view('web.'.$settings->template.'.category',compact('posts','categories'));
}

public function posts($slug)
{
  $posts = Posts::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

  if (!$posts) {
    return null
  }

  $categories = Categories::all();
  $settings = Settings::find(1);
  return view('web.'.$settings->template.'.single',compact('posts','similars','categories'));
}
```

Finally reduce your routes to a single route:

```
Route::get('/{slug}','HomeController@show')->name('show');
```

Note that this route need to be the last route on your routes file, since it will catch anything. Making it the last one will give the chance for other routes being more specific.

Answer (score 0):

According to the the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#explicit-binding) you can do something like this:

```
Route::bind('user', function ($value) {
    return App\User::where('name', $value)->first() ?? abort(404);
});
```

on RouteServiceProvider boot

Comment: could you please refer document.